# Ruby on Rails on IIS7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis-7, ironruby

Due to client requirements, I need to get Ruby on Rails working on IIS7. I'd like to hear recommendations which version of Ruby to choose (IronRuby vs. Ruby) and the best approach for using IIS7 (ISAPI Rewrite, IronRuby.Rack, FastCGI). Also, what is the reliability of the above options. I've never done this on a Windows environment using IIS, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with FastCGI. IronRuby.Rack is not in production mode yet.